# PHP MySQLi Get Associative Array from prepared statement

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I need to get an associative array of values from a MySQL table for a page in my website. I understand that this can be done using
    $stmt->get_result();
This seems to be disabled on my server and I do not have access to the PHP.ini file. Is it possible to get an associative array of values using prepared statements with converting the mysqli_stmt to a mysqli_result?

Comment: Without any code or information about errors it will be hard to help you. Specific functions on PHP are not typically disabled, so perhaps something else is wrong.

Comment: what would the point be of disabling fetch calls, but leaving query calls intact? That's just... stupid. There's no other way to put that. "oh no, `select *` is dangerous!" but then still allow `drop table users;`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It is the server, I contacted the hosting company. In addition, the code works fine on my xampp server that I use at home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have mysqlnd driver available, you will get an undefined reference when trying to call `$stmt->get_result();`.

[Check this Gist](https://github.com/latentPrion/ii-libmysqlnd/blob/master/lib_iimysqlnd.php)

*A PHP library which provides several of the mysqlnd functions in the mysqli_ namespace, allowing developers to use mysqli prepared statements with fetch_assoc() and fetch_array(), etc, without installing mysqlnd.*